# Wattage recommendation for laser cutter

Tags: laser

We are a mechanical insulation company who is looking to speed up our insulation blanket manufacturing capacity.  Currently all of our patterns are hand laid out, and time consuming.

I am currently looking for recommendations on laser cutters for cutting needled fiberglass mat approximately 1in thick.  If we are going to the effort of adding this, it will need to be able to cut .016 aluminum sheeting and .030 pvc sheeting too.

I have a lot of history with CNC machining but no experience with lasers.  5x10ft table is a must to accommodate 60in rolls of glass mat.  Would 1000 watts get the job done?  Will $50,000usd get us in the ballpark?

Comment: PVC contains compounds which release chlorine gas when cut with a laser. I've seen a photo of a laser cutter which was used for cutting pvc foam board and it was destroyed. The operator replaces the machine on a scheduled basis, but the gas is also dangerous/fatal to humans. For your other requirements, consider visiting one of the many laser forums if an answer does not appear here.

Comment: Thanks very much for the information about the gases!

Answer (score 1):

You can find information about CO2 lasers from various sources, including technical journals, scientific publications, engineering websites, and industrial laser manufacturers. I'd like to recommend MIMOWORK Laser, a company specialized in supplying laser cutting machines. Their website provides a wealth of information about laser cutting applications and materials. By visiting the MIMOWORK Laser website,[material overview](https://www.mimowork.com/your-business/material-overview/)

you can access detailed information about CO2 laser applications and a variety of materials. Additionally, the MIMOWORK team offers customized solutions tailored to different production applications. Feel free to reach out to them directly for further assistance.